# Hide Code issue in Static library - Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, static-libraries

I created a Static library in Swift, I built it and then I import it in external project and everything work well.

My problem is that if code in static library crashes (for example array outbound) I see debug on the line crashed of the library (entire class code) while I created it for hiding code inside it.

I have to set some settings for hiding code in static library and not active debug on it?

Comment: Who are you trying to hide the code from? If you use a release configuration, crashes shouldn't show symbol names, instead they will show addresses unless you symbolicate them.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. I created static library (with storyboard etc) and then I import it in a swift iOS project and It works well but when I have a crash in library code I see exception in line crashed in library (I can see the code in static library). hypothetical user of the static library can see the code if it crashed @EmilioPelaez